# Using html tags without <html> tag?

Tags: html

So i have an example , In my example.html
,I am using

```
<h1>example</h1>
```

While running with browser it is giving correct output.
But still I am finding how these tags works without `<html>` tag.

My finding says -

- .html extension will consider these tags
- Latest browsers is considering

Is there any other valuable answer regrading this?

Comment: In most cases it works without tags, but there might be a chance that things get not displayed or displayed the wrong way.

Comment: Not fully sure of that your exact doubt is but the primary source for content detection is the `Content-Type` HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

The [specification defines the HTML element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element) as having start and end tags that may be omitted.

If you don't include them explicitly, the parser is required to imply the start and end of the element from context (which it can do unambiguously).

> An html element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside
>   the html element is not a comment. An html element's end tag can be
>   omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.